# Draw string with NSString drawing in front of UIImageView 

Tags: ios4

I am really new to iOS developing and need to draw a string in front of a UIImageView. I need a little flexibillity (font, color, position, size) and think that UIlabel won't fit my needs. NSString seems to do but I can't get it work.

Does anybody have an example how to draw a string with NSString drawing in front of a UIImageView?

Thanks and kind regards,

Timo

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it with UILabel :-)

Bye,

Timo